# need a regular expression to match tel number

Tags: regex

I want to match expression like `(010)12345678` or `010-12345678`. Now my regular expression is `\(?\d{3}[)-]\d{8}`, but it where match expression like `(010-12345678`. How should I write a true regular expression?

EDIT:

I write a right regex like `(\(\d{3}\)|[^(]\d{3}-)\d{8}` that can meet my needs.

Comment: To write *a true regular expression* you could try a bit harder. Did you hear of say `|` alternation operator?

Comment: I write a right regex like `(\(\d{3}\)|[^(]\d{3}-)\d{8}` that can meet my needs.

Comment: Great, but I think `^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})-\d{8}$` would be better unless you are using it inside  a regex method that requires a full string match (e.g. Java `matches()`, or HTML5 pattern). Where  are you using the regex?

Comment: it's not perfect (works with single bracket as well), but a start: https://regex101.com/r/bC5uK8/1

Comment: Oh, I meant `(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)[0-9]{8}` or `^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)[0-9]{8}$` - the hyphen must be part of the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `(\(\d{3}\)|[^(]\d{3}-)\d{8}` will also match a non-`(` before  a number that starts with 3 digits and `-` due to `[^(]`.

You need to remove it and use

```
(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{8}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV7rR8/1). Or an anchored version:

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{8}$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV7rR8/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)` - Group 1 matching either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `\(\d{3}\)` - `(` followed with 3 digits and a literal `)`
  - `|` -  or
  - `\d{3}-`  - 3 digits and a literal `-`
- `\d{8}`  - 8 digits
- `$`  - end of string.

*Depending on the regex engine*, `\d` might need replacing with `[0-9]`.